# Java: Sorting an ArrayList isn't working

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have a piece of code which fills an `ArrayList<Integer>` with random integers from 10 to 99 (two digit numbers). It is then supposed to iterate through the array and sort it using bubble sort (or exchange sort, to be honest, I'm not quite sure what the difference is). However, the output that I get is really weird. Attached is the code and example output from it.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SortingAnArrayList
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
        Random r = new Random();

        for ( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
        {
            int rNum = 10 + r.nextInt(90);
            al.add( rNum );
        }
        System.out.println( "ArrayList before: " + al);
        ArrayList<Integer> sortedAl = sortArrayList(al);
        System.out.println( "ArrayList after : " + sortedAl);
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> sortArrayList( ArrayList<Integer> a )
    {
        boolean loop;
        ArrayList<Integer> b = a;
        do
        {
            loop = false;
            for ( int i = 0; i < a.size() - 2; i++ )
            {
                if ( b.get(i) > b.get(i + 1) )
                {
                    loop = true;
                    int temp = b.get(i);
                    b.remove(i);
                    b.add( i, b.get(i+1) );
                    b.remove(i+1);
                    b.add( i+1, temp );
                }
            }
        } while (loop);

        return b;
    }
}
```

***OUTPUT #1***

```
ArrayList before: [45, 33, 75, 51, 91, 93, 54, 91, 90, 38, 31, 85, 15, 33, 61, 51, 83, 36, 48, 18]
ArrayList after : [93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 18]
```

***OUTPUT 2***

```
ArrayList before: [73, 39, 68, 54, 12, 63, 90, 55, 53, 24, 14, 80, 58, 12, 64, 25, 82, 27, 20, 55]
ArrayList after : [12, 12, 20, 55, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 55]
```

Please help as I'm not quite sure where I went wrong with the code. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Comment: Hi, we don't do simple "why isn't my code working?" questions on Stackoverflow. But when you `remove` element `i`, `i+1` becomes the new `i`. Instead of removing and adding, use the `set` method (`b.set(i, b.get(i+1)); b.set(i+1, temp);`.

Answer (score 2):

What about `Collections` :

```
Collections.sort(al);
```

Your main thread will be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        int rNum = 10 + r.nextInt(90);
        al.add(rNum);
    }
    System.out.println("ArrayList before: " + al);
    Collections.sort(al);
    System.out.println("ArrayList after : " + al);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
loop = true;
int temp = b.get(i);
b.remove(i);
b.add( i, b.get(i) );
b.remove(i+1);
b.add( i+1, temp );
```

When you call `b.remove(i),` you decrease indexes after i by 1.

Comment: Also, for ( int i = 0; i < a.size() - 1; i++ ) not for ( int i = 0; i < a.size() - 2; i++ )

Answer (score 1):

```
b.add( i, b.get(i+1) );
```

should be

```
b.add( i, b.get(i) );
```

because by `b.remove(i);` in the line before every item behind the position `i` is shifted one position to the left an thereby changes it index by `-1`. This is because you are working on a `List`. Your implementation should work on an `array` where the position is not shifted on a remove.

You should read the documentation about [`remove` of the `List` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-).

> Removes the element at the specified position in this list (optional
>   operation). **Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one
>   from their indices)**. Returns the element that was removed from the
>   list.

Answer (score 1):

The intention is to swap the two, causing more ordering.
This can best be done swapping just the *values*, as:

```
                int temp = b.get(i);
                b.set(i, b.get(i+1));
                b.set(i+1, temp);
```

Removing the i-th element causes that `get(i+1)` now is another, next integer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code. I have tested it:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> sortArrayList( ArrayList<Integer> a )
    {
    boolean loop;
    ArrayList<Integer> b = a;
    do
    {

        loop = false;
        for ( int i = 0; i < a.size() - 2; i++ )
        {
            if ( b.get(i) > b.get(i + 1) )
            {
                loop = true;
                int temp = b.get(i);
//              b.remove(i);
                b.set( i, b.get(i+1) );
//              b.remove(i+1);
                b.set( i+1, temp );
            }
        }
        System.out.println( "ArrayList b : " + b);
    } while (loop);

    return b;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
ArrayList before: [81, 46, 89, 39, 80, 15, 40, 32, 75, 13, 82, 45, 97, 25, 62, 61, 17, 18, 18, 54]
ArrayList after : [13, 15, 17, 18, 18, 25, 32, 39, 40, 45, 46, 61, 62, 75, 80, 81, 82, 89, 97, 54]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not call remove and add, since this has to copy all the remaining elements. Just use `set(index, value);`

```
loop = true;
int temp = b.get(i);
b.set( i, b.get(i+1) );
b.set( i+1, temp );
```

Or, since `set` returns the previous value:

```
loop = true;
b.set(i, b.set(i+1, b.get(i)));
```

Answer (score 0):

you should call `add()` before `remove()`，like this：

```
    loop = true;
    int temp = b.get(i);
    b.add( i, b.get(i+1) );
    b.remove(i+1);
    b.add( i+1, temp );
    b.remove(i+2);
```

however using `set()` is the best choice.